# pusher channel.bind cant access data outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hi i have vuejs2 with pusher
and this is my code inside my created methods

```
console.log(this.orders) // this working good outside channel.bind
var pusher = new Pusher('my pusher key', {
    cluster: 'ap2'
});
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data)
{
    console.log('anything here') // this working good
    console.log(this.orders) // i gat here undefinded
});
```

now ive tried to change watchers or fire any function in my code i always gat undefinded inside

```
channel.bind
```

how can i fix this ..
thanks